# Linux bash, getting getopt default parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopt

I'm trying to write a moderately difficult bash program, but somehow I cannot parse command line parameters and set default parameters with getopt.

Getopt is somehow ignoring optional parameters, setting them after the --, which denotes end of parameters.

Simple test, where l(list) is required:

```
getopt -s bash -o l: -l list: -- -l test
```

Produces:

`-l 'test' --`

If I were to define l(list) as optional, then output is:

getopt -s bash -o l:: -l list:: -- -l test

`-l '' -- 'test'`

I used [this example](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt) as a base, but as of my testing, even this script does not work as intended(setting arga value to something produces always default value).

OS: Linux, getopt -V=getopt from util-linux 2.27

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: IIRC getopts will only work with short options, not long ones. The code in that tutorial is doing its own parsing to iterate through options. There are almost *certainly* a lot of questions/answers/examples on SO (and the rest of the web) about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the man page:

> A simple short option is a '-' followed by a short option character.  If the option has  a  required
>          argument, it may be written directly after the option character or as the next parameter (i.e. separated by whitespace on the command line).  **If the option has an optional argument, it must be  written directly after the option character if present**.

So you want

```
$ getopt -s bash -o l:: -l list:: -- -ltest
 -l 'test' --
```

Similarly, for optional long args, you must provide the argument in a specific way:

required

```
$ getopt -s bash -o l: -l list: -- --list foo
 --list 'foo' --
$ getopt -s bash -o l: -l list: -- --list=foo
 --list 'foo' --
```

optional

```
$ getopt -s bash -o l:: -l list:: -- --list foo
 --list '' -- 'foo'
$ getopt -s bash -o l:: -l list:: -- --list=foo
 --list 'foo' --
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the relevant part in manual. I read the manual, but seems I skimmed over it, was too long. getopt seems a little inconsistent in style between mandatory arguments and optional arguments. Seems I had Idée fixe, that all programs in linuxland supporting long parameters use `program --param <arg|undefined>`

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight. I didn't even notice the difference -- I don't do enough bash these days to remember the details without typing `man foo` constantly.